# ClassCastException in Kotlin even though the conditional statement checks that it's of right type

Tags: java, kotlin, casting

I'm burning cycles trying to understand why I'm getting a cast error when I know for a fact that it's a string.

Anyone else seen this in Kotlin? (it fails at the second to last line).

```kotlin
val stringValue =
    if (attributesMap[it] !is String) { // same as !(obj is String)
        gson.toJson(attributesMap[it])
    } else if (attributesMap[it] == null) {
        ""
    } else {
        if (attributesMap[it] is String)
            logger.info("it's a string wth...${attributesMap[it]}")
            
        attributesMap[it] // <--- The stacktrace shows this line as the culprit, and the above "it's a string line" is printed out as well
    }
```

Here's the error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.util.ArrayList and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

Updated 1: this started happening after I upgraded from Kotlin 1.4.10 to 1.5.30. Also the input that it fails on is a string that looks like an array: ["item1", "item2"]

Comment: I think need more information regarding the `attributesMap` data type as well, can help to share?

Comment: It seems like you must have removed something. Nowhere in your shown code do you cast anything to String so it shouldn’t be possible to get that error for any of the lines of code shown.

Comment: I haven't removed anything, that's the problem. It started when I upgraded from Kotlin 1.4.10 to 1.5.30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem is that `attributesMap[it]` is not a property itself. It's actually a function call `attributesMap.get(it)`.
That's why compiler is not able to smart cast it.

Also, I am not sure of your order of `if` statements. If `attributesMap[it] !is String` is false, `attributesMap[it] == null` will definitely be false.

Try this code, see if it works for you.

```kotlin
val value = attributes[it] // Store the value beforehand
val stringValue =
    if(value == null)
        ""
    else if(value is String)
        value
    else
        gson.toJson(value)
```

You can also replace this `if-else` ladder with a `when` statement.

[Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/2W4UKzKC4)

Comment: You're right!!!! I started storing the value before and using that variable in my conditional statements and everything started working again. BTW this problem started after I upgraded from Kotlin 1.4.10 to 1.5.30 so something must have changed.